# Which state of thread will be when we call LockSupport.unpark()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

We know that when we call LockSupport.park() the thread A will be WAITTING and wait for another thread to call LockSupport.unpark(). So when we call it, which the state of thread A will be?

RUNNABLE?

It can't be BLOCKED, because the description of it in API is :

```
Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor lock.
```

When we use the LockSupport.park() API, we need't to acquire a monitor lock, not behave like Object.wait().

So RUNNABLE state will be, it's right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the thread has been started.

[`LockSupport.unpark()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark(java.lang.Thread))

> Makes available the permit for the given thread

which enables the current thread for thread scheduling purposes. Exactly what  `RUNNABLE` means.